# Minimal Office365 ASPX with Suitebar only, no MasterPage

Tags: office-365, master-page, custom-masterpage, aspx, office-365-developer

I am no MasterPage wizard so after some trial and error wonder if MP Wizards have some better insights

Objective is to create a ASPX with only to the Office365 SuiteBar

Below gets me the SuiteBar, but none of the interactions work

Other questions:

- I copied references from a dutch tenant, they also include Microsoft built numbers
  What are the generic, non-language dependent, urls?

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint"
namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>
    <title>MUX</title>

    <!-- COPY/PASTE of CSS files that Office365 HomePage loaded -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" id="favicon">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/nl-NL/Themable/Core%20Styles/pagelayouts15.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1043/styles/Themable/corev15.css?rev=DpGD2cp9%2FI3Y3JMmPt%2BrgQ%3D%3DTAG206">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1539.005/css/shellg2coremincss_992458dd.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1539.005/css/shellg2corecss_4190db1b.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://portal.office.com/data.theme?action=tc&tc=00967E|FFED00|000000|FFFFFF&tt=G2&tv=f24fc757-b25a-4c71-8c16-3b65b92e23de&l=">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1539.005/css/shellg2pluscss_891570d8.css">

    <!-- COPY/PASTE of Scriptfiles for a Minimal Master Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1539.005/nl-NL/JSC/CoreMinShellG2Bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.5910.1208/sp.init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/mQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>

    <!--MYCONTENT-->
    <style>
        #ASPXPageContainer{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<form runat="server">
    <div id="suiteBarDelta" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-fullWidth noindex">
        <!--COPY/PASTE of standard Office365 Homepage -->
    </div>
    <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
    <div id="ASPXPageContainer">
    <!--MYCONTENT-->
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Updates

- Added CSS to fix header and scroll my own content
- Stripped some language-language references from CSS references  Still required for pagelayouts15.css

Comment: I only tried with one of the css files, but removing the locale from the URL worked: `https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1539.005/css/shellg2pluscss_891570d8.css`

Comment: That url was previously `https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1539.005/nl-NL/css/shellg2pluscss_891570d8.css`.  Also, these files change on occasion, and the identifier at the end (891570d8, in this case) changes when this happens.  Something to look out for if you want any updates they push out to the SuiteBar.